# Is Wheelock's Latin comprehensive?

Tags: wheelocks-latin

Is Wheelock's Latin complete?

By this I mean precisely the following:

1. In reading the classical authors, will there be constructions, exceptions, etc. that are not covered by the textbook?
2. When I write using only the grammar taught in the book, will I make mistakes (e.g. because a rule has been omitted)?

Comment: In few decades, the TLL (https://thesaurus.badw.de/en/project.html) may reach its goal.

Answer (score 15):

Wheelock's is fairly comprehensive, and usually if it doesn't cover something it's because it's a rarer exception. You should be able to read everything "Classical" (basically 1st century BCE - 1st century CE) just fine using it, but having a proper grammar for those less frequent encounters will be useful.

Concerning your second point, though, yes you will make mistakes, but not because a "rule" has been omitted, but because there is much, much more to language than a bunch of rules. Word choice and idiom will play a more important role in how correct your Latin is than just knowing grammatical rules. Language isn't a matter of 1-to-1 correspondences between languages. The very way they word things can be radically different from how we conceive them.

But the only way to counter that is to just read a lot of Latin first. No primer will get you there.

Comment: Thank you for the first point, it answers my question perfectly. But the second point I am only talking of grammatical mistakes, obviously word choice and idiom are fundamental elements of composition

Comment: @user989070 You might be surprised at how much overlap there is between grammar and style. I've seen this a lot among people learning English as a second language: they put getting correct grammar above learning to communicate, and consequently they they don't master the grammar—which is just how you put words together to communicate.

Comment: @BenKovitz It's quite funny, because I happened to learn English as a second language

Answer (score 4):

One omission that I've always found fairly glaring is the relative clause of purpose. These are mentioned only in the notes to one reading passage but deserve more formal treatment, given how common they are. When I've taught from Wheelock's, I've expanded its discussion of relative clauses of characteristic into a broader discussion of relative clauses that have a subjunctive verb.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of Wheelock's "Latin." Much better, I believe, to use Allen & Greenough's New Latin Grammar (https://archive.org/details/allengreenoughsn00alleiala).

If you're looking for a primer, the older texts are the best because they're the clearest. For example, Gildersleeve's Latin Grammar by Gildersleeve and Lodge (https://archive.org/details/gildersleeveslat00gilduoft).

For beginners, I recommend "A First Year Latin Course" (1914) by Smiley and Storke, originally published by the American Book Company.
(https://ia600902.us.archive.org/32/items/afirstyearlatin00storgoog/afirstyearlatin00storgoog.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the grammar in Wheelocks when you write, you will make mistakes, not because of what is missing from the book, but because of the mistakes that LaFleur, the new editor, has added to recent editions.  For example, a recent addition is "eiscum" for "cum eis" or "cum iis": the word does not exist in classical Latin, as -cum can only be suffixed to actual pronouns, not demonstratives.  Instead, "cum iis" is found throughout Latin, as in Cicero *In Verrem* 2.2.29, *Pro Sestio* 51, and countless other places; "iiscum" and "eiscum" never occur in ancient Latin.  It's a shame what LaFleur has done to Wheelock, which used to be a decent textbook.

Comment: Good note! That must be from the 7th edition, right? I never taught from that edition. I know some years back Rick was on the internet asking about corrections. He's probably receptive to an email to fix that point.